# Javascript - Why is alert() ignored in my program

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning javascript using a book and they give this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN”
“http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd”>
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>
<body>
<script language=”JavaScript” type=”text/javascript”>
var firstNumber = 15;
var secondNumber = 10;
var answer;
answer = 15 / 10;
alert(answer);
alert(15 / 10);
answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
alert(answer);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load it, alert only pops up twice instead of three times. Why is this?

Comment: I see it is working, at least in this demo http://fiddle.jshell.net/ARwkK/ are all alerts not showing or one of them? is there any additional code in the page?

Comment: The quotes `“` look weird. Are they in the source code?

Comment: Are you using the fancy quotes in your real code? Because a browser will likely throw up on those...

Comment: Ahh, ok. I just noticed the quotes. I wonder why KomodoEdit doesn't close quotes. Can anyone recommend other editors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes you were using are doing something wierd and preventing the code to run. Wasn't getting any error just ignored...

Anyway try this working fine in FF, Chrome and Safari:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var firstNumber = 15;
var secondNumber = 10;
var answer;
answer = 15 / 10;
alert("1: " + answer);
alert("2: " + 15 / 10);
answer = firstNumber / secondNumber;
alert("3: " + answer);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right. It's the quotes. The fancy or smart quotes screwing things up. When I copied and pasted quotes it was the fancy quotes. Works fine using a plain text file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you've not copied the code exactly and somewhere in the real code you have a syntax error, or possibly a non-printable control character.  You code is then crashing before it reaches the third alert.  Check the error console - it should show up there (I assume you're using Firefox. which imho tends to be best for debugging Javascript).

Comment: I assume that you mean the Error Console? I can't imagine that Firefox floods the event log with every Javascript error it encounters?